How To Access Function on A Different Directory?
So, My directory is looking like this :
Project.py
|
|--- sales_management.py
|     |
|     |--- data.py
|     |--- input2.py
|     |--- reports.py
|     |--- statics.py
|
|--- main_program.py

So, in "data.py", "input2.py", "reports.py", and "statics.py" are bunch of function. And, I want to use those function in the "main_program.py". How to do that?
I already tried using __init__.py. But, it's still popping out as ModuleNotFoundError.
I make a new module named __init__.py inside of the "sales_management" directory to change it into package. And I do :
from data import funct1, funct2, ...
from input2 import  funct3, funct4, ...
.
.

Then, on my "main_program" I import sales_management. But, when I tried to call funct1 it shows as ModuleNotFoundError.
I tried with an empty __init__.py. Then importing this on my main_program.py :
from sales_management.data import funct1
from sales_management.data import funct2
from sales_management.data import funct3
from sales_management.data import funct4
from sales_management.data import funct5
from sales_management.input2 import funct6
from sales_management.input2 import funct7
.
.
.

It works. I could call the funct1 and it did work. But I don't want those bunch of import inside of my "main_program.py". How to fix that?

If you wish to minimize the lines of import statement, why don't you import using:
from sales_management.data import funct1, funct2, funct3, funct4, funct5
from sales_management.input2 import funct6, funct7

You can also write a class in sales_management.data.py file and import the class into your main_program.py.
# data.py

class Data:
   def __init__(self):
      pass
   def func():
      pass
   def func2():
      pass

# main_program.py

from sales_management.data import Data

if __name__ == "__main__":
     data_obj = Data()
     data_obj.func()
     data_obj.func2()

If you wish not to initialise an object, you can use staticmethod to call functions without initialising the object.

You can try to initialise a specialized file in which you are going to make all these imports 'function_imports.py' (it should be at the level of your main folder). After that try to import everything from this module with just one line of codefrom function_imports.py import *. With this your main is going to be cleaned from all these imports.
